# Openxml image content control

Tags: c#, openxml

I have an image stored in my database in `base64` format. The first question I want to ask here is that is it the best way to store it ?

Next, I am trying to put this image in a Word document via `openxml`. I have already filled the document with simple text but I am unable to convert my `base64` string to an image and then put it in the word document.

Any suggestions or guidance would be appreciable.

Comment: Base64 seems like a bad decision, images will be around 1.3~1.4 times bigger than the original. You can save them as **blob**s. But for the converting there is **Convert.FromBase64String()**, if the converting is the problem, and not the placement. See [How do I decode a base64 encoded string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134837/how-do-i-decode-a-base64-encoded-string)

Comment: My problem is more about the placement but thanks for the converting tips

Answer (score 1):

To add an image use can use an `ImagePart` object which you then pass a stream to. This is detailed [on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb497430(v=office.15).aspx),

```
MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;
ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    imagePart.FeedData(stream);
}
AddImageToBody(wordprocessingDocument, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart));
```

`ImagePart.FeedData` takes a Stream so where the example uses a FileStream, you can swap that out and use a MemoryStream.

```
var bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(yourBase64String);
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    imagePart.FeedData(stream);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, method `AddImageToBody` is not found

Comment: Thats a snippet from the msdn page. Look at the link and you will see the full `AddImageToBody` method.