# Why does this fail to decode a base64 string?

Tags: java, encoding, radix

I have created some code that should work:

```
String input = "PONT4uYmTYwiP0omcAxZG8a3vKI=";
String expectedOut = "3ce353e2e6264d8c223f4a26700c591bc6b7bca2";

Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
byte[] outAsByte = decoder.decode(input);
String output = new String(outAsByte, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(output);
```

(based on [How do I decode a base64 encoded string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134837/how-do-i-decode-a-base64-encoded-string) - I know that it's in C#)

Surprisingly this outputs the following:

```
PONT4uYmTYwiP0omcAxZG8a3vKI=
<?S??&M?"?J&pY???
```

Why does this print a bunch of gibberish instead of the the expected output?

Edit: I got the expected output using this bash command:

```
echo -n PONT4uYmTYwiP0omcAxZG8a3vKI= | base64 -d | xxd -p
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`xxd`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xxd1.html)'s man page

> xxd creates a hex dump of a given file or standard input.

You're taking a hex dump for the decoded value.

You can reproduce it with the utility provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9655275/438154)

```
System.out.println(Hex.encodeHexString(outAsByte));
```

generates

```
3ce353e2e6264d8c223f4a26700c591bc6b7bca2
```

which matches your

```
                  //  3ce353e2e6264d8c223f4a26700c591bc6b7bca2
String expectedOut = "3ce353e2e6264d8c223f4a26700c591bc6b7bca2";
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I had misunderstood what `xxd` did, totally confusing me.

Answer (score 2):

How did you come up with the expected outcome?

Decoding your input using base64 and UTF-8 results in `<ãSâæ&M"?J&pYÆ·¼¢`, which is your actual outcome, apart from the UTF-8 specific characters.

Comment: I used `echo -n PONT4uYmTYwiP0omcAxZG8a3vKI= | base64 -d | xxd -p`, If you don't have bash try it here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php. The [`xxd`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_xxd.htm) command seems to be where the magic is happening, although I have no idea what it is doing... My first guess was that it was doing some sort of text conversion, but that seems wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`0x3c == '<'`   etc.

The expected output should really be `0x3c 0xe3 ...`