# Upload JSON and HttpPostedFile to MVC via jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I POST  `<input type="file" id="uploadStudent" />` uploaded file to mvc controller in this scenario?

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/Home/CompleteAttendeeType",
  contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "JSON",
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    //PostedFile: "I AM CONFUSED HOW TO UPLOAD?",
    AttendeeType: 1,
    LicenseNumber: $("#txtLicenseNumber").val(),
    LicenseState: $("#txtLicenseState").val(),
    SchoolName: $("#txtSchoolName").val(),
    SchoolLocation: $("#txtSchoolLocation").val()
  })
})
```

MVC

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CompleteAttendeeType(CompleteAttendeeTypeRequest request)
{
  return Json(string.Empty, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public enum AttendeeType
{
  Professional,
    Student,
    Owner,
    Guest
}

public class CompleteAttendeeTypeRequest
{
  public HttpPostedFile PostedFile { get; set; }
  public AttendeeType AttendeeType { get; set; }

  public string LicenseNumber { get; set; }
  public string LicenseState { get; set; }

  public string SchoolName { get; set; }
  public string SchoolLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can use `FormData`. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681) for an example

Comment: @StephenMuecke — That won't give JSON output

Comment: @Quentin, Not sure what your saying. OP can either serialize a form or add each property individually - e.g. `formdata.append(LicenseNumber, $("#txtLicenseNumber").val());` etc which will bind to the `CompleteAttendeeTypeRequest` model in the controller.

Comment: @StephenMuecke — The request is being formatted as application/json not multipart/form-data. You can't get application/json out of FormData objects.

Comment: OP want to upload a file and properties so that they can be bound to a model. It does not need to be _JSON output_ - but it does need to work which is what the linked answer does :)

Answer (score 0):

First use the [File API to read the contents of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4950836/19068).

Then you need to express the data in a format that can be represented in JSON. If the data is a string, then you can just use that. Otherwise, you will need to convert it. [Converting it to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978156/get-base64-encode-file-data-from-input-form) is one approach.

Then you'll have data in a variable that you can include in the object you pass to `JSON.stringify`.

If you encoded it as base64, you'll need to [decode it on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134837/how-do-i-decode-a-base64-encoded-string).