# Javascript - sending encoding binary (zip) file data and decoding it in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, encoding, zip, decoding

I have **zip file** that I want to encode and send it as string and decode and save it in server side:

This the code of the encoding in client (JS):

```
var fileAsText = ''
var reader = new FileReader()
reader.onload = function (event) {
  fileAsText = encodeURIComponent(event.target.result)
}
reader.readAsText(zipFile)
```

`zipFile` is the input File object (uploaded by the user).

The `fileAsText` string I'm sending as `Post` inside `JSON` (this is the reason I'm using `encodeURIComponent`)

Everything works fine, but in server side I want to take this string and **decode it back** to binary (zip file) and extract it. and I want to get **exactly the same file** the user upload in client side.

This is my code in **c#**:

```
 using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("fileTest.zip", FileMode.Create)))
 {
      bw.Write(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(fileAsText));
 }
```

**The problem:** I don't get the same file (the binary data is diffrent)
I believe the decoder `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` is not fit to `encodeURIComponent`

Any idea how to get the same file binary data uploaded by the user?

Comment: You probably shouldn't read it as text... just send the blob as is... and then use formData to combine both json and files. From the moment you did read it as text using filereader you have gotten a broken data. Javascript can't handle binary strings so well

Comment: @Endless I know, there is a reason I read it as text, it's complicated to explain (it's limitation) please find a solution if I have to use  reader.readAsText Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to post it as json? It's a bad idea. you can send it as it's `xhr.send(zipFile)` or use multipart upload if you need more fields ([FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData))

Comment: I'm using Json RPC as communication  https://github.com/Astn/JSON-RPC.NET so I can send only Json to the server. I can't send File to the server

Comment: Then i suggest you read is `asDataURL` (base64) but that will give you a overhead and ~3x more bandwidth

Comment: And how decode it in c#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134837/how-do-i-decode-a-base64-encoded-string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126759/discussion-between-chezihoyzer-and-endless).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary string don't work well in javascript best would be to post it as multipart form data.

But if you really need to post it as json cuz of some server restriction then the best is to send it as base64

A quick fix is just changing `readAsText` to `readAsDataURL`
Then on the server side convert it back to binary using `Convert.FromBase64String`

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString);
```