# I have a problem with decoding from base64

Tags: c#, jwt, base64

In my client application I try to decode a JWT, but it keeps giving me this error

```
System.FormatException: 'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.'
```

I am trying to decode like this:

```
 //token = eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE3MTExODcyODcsImlzcyI6IlRlc3QuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiVGVzdC5jb20ifQ.pgzHJVC-iuvPaMuYzFNwPREFQsUVsLlKia11AM3ai1Y
 string[] tokens = token.Split('.');

// first tokenPart = eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9 and works
// second tokenPart = eyJleHAiOjE3MTExODcyODcsImlzcyI6IlRlc3QuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiVGVzdC5jb20ifQ and fails

 foreach (string tokenPart in tokens) 
 {
     string decodedString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(tokenPart));
 }
```

The error appears for the second tokenPart, an example of this is

```
eyJleHAiOjE3MTExODQ3MDUsImlzcyI6IlRlc3QuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiVGVzdC5jb20ifQ
```

When I tried to decode the same string online [here](https://www.base64decode.org/) it works without problems, the result of the decoding is this:

```
{"exp":1711179891,"iss":"Test.com","aud":"Test.com"}
```

I found [How do I decode a base64 encoded string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134837/how-do-i-decode-a-base64-encoded-string) and tried all the answers, but nothing helped me.

The string was produced in my web application like this

```
  public string GenerateJSONWebToken(int userID, string key, string issuer)
  {
      SymmetricSecurityKey securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
      SigningCredentials credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

      JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(
          issuer,
          issuer, 
          null,
          expires: DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10),
          signingCredentials: credentials);

      return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
  }
```

Comment: Please don't [re-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78210164/3001761). One other thing did occur - your token is 70 characters long; which isn't a multiple of 4. As the message suggests, there's a problem with the (lack of) _padding_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I deleted the first question because it started from trying to decode the entire string in stead of splitting, and my problem was not with that, so it makes perfect sense to me to make a new question about the actual problem, that is NOT a repost

Comment: @jonrsharpe Aha, so the problem is that my token is 70 characters, so how should I retrieve the information than  as this online decode does ?

Comment: How was the string produced

Comment: ...add the padding?

Comment: @Magnus I edited the question so you can see how the string was produced

Comment: Is your goal to get the properties of the token or to validate it?

Comment: @Magnus My client needs to read the expiration datetime, so it can request a new token before it expires, that is my goal